# How to aggregate rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains values by country (and by region in certain countries) and which looks like this:

[image]

For each country that is repeated, I would add the values by regions so that there is only one row per country and obtain the following file:

[image]

How can I do this in Python? Since I'm really new to Python, I don't mind having a long set of instructions, as long as the procedure is clear, rather than a single line of code, compacted but hard to understand.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to study the [split-apply-combine paradigm](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) of Pandas DataFrame manipulation.  You can do a lot with it.  What you want to do is common, and can be accomplished in one line.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": ["a","b","a","b","c"], "bar": [6,5,4,3,2]})
>>> df 
  foo  bar
0   a    6
1   b    5
2   a    4
3   b    3
4   c    2
>>> df.groupby("foo").sum() 
     bar
foo     
a     10
b      8
c      2
```

Comment: Thank you. Using with `reset_index()`, it gives perfectly what I wanted.

Comment: If I gave you a correct answer, Stack Overflow (and I) would appreciate it if you would mark my answer as correct.  Thanks!